# Inconsistent Memcached PHP session read error after migrating to PHP 7

Tags: php, memcached

We are migrating an app from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7.3.
The app use memcached to store sessions data, and AJAX requests to display session related information.

```
  session.save_handler = memcached
  session.save_path = "localhost:11211"
```

Memcached behaviour is **not consistent** when **concurrent** AJAX requests try to read the session, some fails with error :

```
session_start(): Failed to read session data: memcached (path: localhost:11211)
```

On the same page, when reloading the page, **the same AJAX requests may succeed or fails**.

This behaviour did not happen when the app was running with **PHP 5.4**.

If using files session handler (default values php.ini) :

```
  session.save_handler = files
  session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/sessions"
```

then the errors don't happen anymore and all requests succeed.

Disabling session locking also solves the problem :

```
  memcached.sess_locking = Off
```

I'm not fan of disabling session locking since it may lead to other concurrent access issues.

Does anyone has similar experience or know the way out? Thanks in advance

PS:
Previous configuration where it works fine is

```
  Debian 7, PHP 5.4, memcached 2.0.1 and libmemcached 1.0.8
```

New configuration where error occurs :

```
  Debian 9, PHP 7.3, memcached 3.1.13 and libmemcached 1.0.18.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the "number of times to retry locking the session lock" decreases the number of failure.

```
  memcached.sess_lock_retries = 50
```

Default value is 5.

In my case, no more errors happen when increased to at least 30.
I've set it to 50 and hope it will be enough.